# How would I change the movement keys to WASD from the arrow keys using something similar to this?

Tags: javascript

This is a simplified part of a bigger game I am making. The current movement is the arrow keys, but I want them to be WASD. I saw a youtube on this and that's how I made this. I have expanded it, but can't figure out how to change to WASD. I understand basic keycodes and the way the person made this one is using from keycode left arrow? to keycode down arrow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
var ctx = null;
var gameMap = [
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
];
var tileW = 40, tileH = 40;
var mapW = 10, mapH = 10;
var currentSecond = 0, frameCount = 0, framesLastSecond = 0, lastFrameTime = 0;

var keysDown = {
    37 : false,
    38 : false,
    39 : false,
    40 : false
};

var player = new Character();

function Character()
{
    this.tileFrom   = [1,1];
    this.tileTo     = [1,1];
    this.timeMoved  = 0;
    this.dimensions = [30,30];
    this.position   = [45,45];
    this.delayMove  = 700;
}
Character.prototype.placeAt = function(x, y)
{
    this.tileFrom   = [x,y];
    this.tileTo     = [x,y];
    this.position   = [((tileW*x)+((tileW-this.dimensions[0])/2)),
        ((tileH*y)+((tileH-this.dimensions[1])/2))];
};
Character.prototype.processMovement = function(t)
{
    if(this.tileFrom[0]==this.tileTo[0] && this.tileFrom[1]==this.tileTo[1]) { return false; }

    if((t-this.timeMoved)>=this.delayMove)
    {
        this.placeAt(this.tileTo[0], this.tileTo[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        this.position[0] = (this.tileFrom[0] * tileW) + ((tileW-this.dimensions[0])/2);
        this.position[1] = (this.tileFrom[1] * tileH) + ((tileH-this.dimensions[1])/2);

        if(this.tileTo[0] != this.tileFrom[0])
        {
            var diff = (tileW / this.delayMove) * (t-this.timeMoved);
            this.position[0]+= (this.tileTo[0]<this.tileFrom[0] ? 0 - diff : diff);
        }
        if(this.tileTo[1] != this.tileFrom[1])
        {
            var diff = (tileH / this.delayMove) * (t-this.timeMoved);
            this.position[1]+= (this.tileTo[1]<this.tileFrom[1] ? 0 - diff : diff);
        }

        this.position[0] = Math.round(this.position[0]);
        this.position[1] = Math.round(this.position[1]);
    }

    return true;
}

function toIndex(x, y)
{
    return((y * mapW) + x);
}

window.onload = function()
{
    ctx = document.getElementById('game').getContext("2d");
    requestAnimationFrame(drawGame);
    ctx.font = "bold 10pt sans-serif";

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if(e.c>=37 && e.keyCode<=40) { keysDown[e.keyCode] = true; }
    });
    window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode>=37 && e.keyCode<=40) { keysDown[e.keyCode] = false; }
    });
};

function drawGame()
{
    if(ctx==null) { return; }

    var currentFrameTime = Date.now();
    var timeElapsed = currentFrameTime - lastFrameTime;

    var sec = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000);
    if(sec!=currentSecond)
    {
        currentSecond = sec;
        framesLastSecond = frameCount;
        frameCount = 1;
    }
    else { frameCount++; }

    if(!player.processMovement(currentFrameTime))
    {
        if(keysDown[38] && player.tileFrom[1]>0 && gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0], player.tileFrom[1]-1)]==1) { player.tileTo[1]-= 1; }
        else if(keysDown[40] && player.tileFrom[1]<(mapH-1) && gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0], player.tileFrom[1]+1)]==1) { player.tileTo[1]+= 1; }
        else if(keysDown[37] && player.tileFrom[0]>0 && gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0]-1, player.tileFrom[1])]==1) { player.tileTo[0]-= 1; }
        else if(keysDown[39] && player.tileFrom[0]<(mapW-1) && gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0]+1, player.tileFrom[1])]==1) { player.tileTo[0]+= 1; }

        if(player.tileFrom[0]!=player.tileTo[0] || player.tileFrom[1]!=player.tileTo[1])
        { player.timeMoved = currentFrameTime; }
    }

    for(var y = 0; y < mapH; ++y)
    {
        for(var x = 0; x < mapW; ++x)
        {
            switch(gameMap[((y*mapW)+x)])
            {
                case 0:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#685b48";
                    break;
                default:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#5aa457";
            }

            ctx.fillRect( x*tileW, y*tileH, tileW, tileH);
        }
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = "#0000ff";
    ctx.fillRect(player.position[0], player.position[1],
        player.dimensions[0], player.dimensions[1]);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
    ctx.fillText("FPS: " + framesLastSecond, 10, 20);

    lastFrameTime = currentFrameTime;
    requestAnimationFrame(drawGame);
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<canvas id="game" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Really the other answer is technically better—I just needed more characters :) My point was that these kinds of problems can often be sussed out by taking a step back, framing the question a bit at a time, and pursuing each of the steps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Moved to answer for formatting.)

Here's how you can answer this question yourself:

Goal: Don't look for arrow keys, look for WASD.

1. Identify the code that handles key press events (hint). It appears as though you have mostly narrowed this down already.
2. See if the key codes (hint) match the keys you actually want to use. You've already ascertained they do not, but how to make the change?
3. Search the web for "js arrow key codes" and see if that lines up with anything in your code. (It does.)
4. Find the key codes for the keys you *want* to use. (Perhaps using same reference as above?)
5. Map appropriately to the movements already handled for the arrow keys. (E.g., up-arrow is `w` most likely, so you'd want the current up-arrow handler to fire for `w`.
6. ???
7. Profit.

TL;DR: You're basically done--the missing links are the key codes. *BAM* Self-rescuing prince/ss.

Answer (score 0):

How about add `else if` in the block:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if(e.c>=37 && e.keyCode<=40) { keysDown[e.keyCode] = true; }
    });

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if(e.c>=37 && e.keyCode<=40) { 
           keysDown[e.keyCode] = true; 
        } else if(e.c === 87) {
         // This is the key for "W"
         }
        });
```